# Listview and onItemLongClick doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-listview, uninstallation, onlongclicklistener

i've got a listview with all applications installed.. I need that `onItemLongClick` uninstall the application i click in the listview. The starting code for the onItemLongClick is this one:

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

And this is for uninstall:

```
ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+app.packageName);
        Intent uninstallIntent =
          new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
        startActivity(uninstallIntent);

        return true;
```

i need also insert some parameters and i tryied this one but i have an error in `onItemLongClick`:

```
protected boolean setOnItemLongClickListener(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onItemLongClick(l, v, position, id);// Error

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);

        Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+app.packageName);
        Intent uninstallIntent =
          new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
        startActivity(uninstallIntent);

        return true;
    }
```

how can i solve?

Comment: what is your error? post your logcat here

Comment: not errors on the log cat but syntax: `The method onItemLongClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type ListActivity`.. i have implement `OnItemLongClickListener` in my Main class but if i pass over "MainActivity" i get this suggest: `The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)`

Comment: Did you remember to set listView.setOnLongClickListener(this); ??

Answer (score 1):

try to implement this

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;


yourListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "delete item in position : " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yeah, he just 'overrided the setOnItemLongClickListener.